# Como usar try com while e vetores

Tags: java, for, exceção

Preciso criar um código onde o usuário informe 4 números inteiros e caso qualquer outra coisa seja digitada seja feito um tratamento de exceção.

Estou tendo problemas com o catch, não estou conseguindo fazer que quando ocorra a exceção ele volte ao while sem fazer a contagem do controlador `for`, ou seja preciso que os 4 números sejam inteiros e que não saia do programa até que eles sejam preenchidos corretamente.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int [] vet = new int[4];
        
        boolean erro = true;
        
        for(int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
            erro = true;
            while (erro == true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Informe o " + (i+1) + "º numero: ");
                    vet[i] = sc.nextInt();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Valor inválido");
                    
                    
                }
                erro = !erro;
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa desse código complexo. Você pode só voltar atrás na contagem do `for` quando dá erro. Mas isso por si só não resolve todo o problema. Veja que eu mudei para capturar a exceção específica e limpei o *buffer* do *scanner* que mantém aquele dado quando dá erro (uma falha do Java na minha opinião, mas você tem que lidar). E melhorei mais alguns pontos.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] vet = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Informe o " + (i + 1) + "º numero: ");
                vet[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) { //note que eu capturei a exceção certa
                System.out.println("Valor inválido");
                sc.nextLine(); //precisa disso pra limpar o buffer
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lWk3jg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ontjbvzh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/BackCounterOnError.java).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero! Realmente ficou bem mais limpo assim e a parte de limpar o buffer tb ajudou muito! Havia feito algumas alterações e em uma delas o catch ficava pegando o erro e repetindo até o fim do for, acredito que isso ocorrou por não ter utilizado essa "manhã".